# Objective-C NSString encoding Umlauts

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsstring, diacritics

I have the following issue:

I enter data in a UITextField and then I want to send it to a server. But the data I am entering may contain umlauts (ö, ä, ü, …). Then I get a wrong encoding when passing it to the server. But I am encoding it with UTF8.

```
NSString *s = @"ö";
NSLog(@"%@", s);
NSLog(@"%s", s.UTF8String);
```

What am I doing wrong? In the second line, I see a perfectly fine "ö", but in the third line, I see this: √∂

There are a lot of encoding posts around the Internet, but nothing really solved the problem.

Comment: Is your output log/terminal/whatever being correctly declared/interpreted as UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you encoding or decoding things properly when talking to your server?

Remember that NSString has those wonderful functions:

[`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)

and

[`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)

As for seeing garbage in that third NSLog line output, the "%s" in the format means NSLog is expecting a C-style collection of bytes and it might not be able to display high-ascii values properly.  Whereas "%@" format in NSLogs means NSString objects and all string encodings should work properly for that.

Comment: %s with UTF-8 works for me, providing I have my terminal set up properly.

Comment: @Wevah well of course, %s works for me too... but the issue is does it work with umlauts or other [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)?

Comment: There were actually 2 problems: I did not use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: and I should have put %@ instead or %s in for string formatting. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with UTF8 and NSString, you should probably use `[@"ö" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` to get the NSData object you can send over the network. This will always work fine.